download emails captured via Einstein Activity Capture
I have a script that fetches emails from the EmailMessage object in Salesforce and stores them in my local database. However, after enabling Einstein Activity Capture (EAC), the synced emails no longer appear in the EmailMessage object. As a result, I am unable to fetch these emails and back them up in my database.
I read in a Salesforce article that when using Einstein Activity Capture, captured emails are not stored as standard EmailMessage records in the Salesforce database. Instead, they are stored in Amazon Web Services (AWS) data centers and are only accessible through the Activity Timeline within Salesforce. These emails cannot be directly queried in the database.
Can anyone suggest a workaround to fetch the emails captured via EAC so I can continue to back them up in my local database?

I feel like there's no way to access EAC records.  It's a blackbox dead-end.
